# Implement ASP.NET Identity without a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a site (MVC5) that require a user to login. However I have no control over the user database, instead I have a web services with a method of something like this.

```
public bool LogIn(string username, string password);
```

I need to login the user if it returns true, any idea how to achieve this?

I've read this article
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity but have no idea how to create my own context, stuck in this part since the author doesn't provide downloadable solution example.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ExampleStorageContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    ...
```

Any help will be appreciated and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can simply use [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) to save state of user.

Comment: I don't want to use Session because I need the ASP.Identity features.